# Create A count Features right

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, classification, feature-engineering

I have a table like that:

| PC | USER | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 |

1. for every row show the max connection:

| PC | USER | Period | Max Con Per PC | Max Con Per USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 | 4 | 2 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 | 4 | 3 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 | 4 | 1 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 | 4 | 1 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 | 3 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 | 3 | 3 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 | 3 | 3 |

2. for every row show the COUNT OF the connection:

| PC | USER | Period | Max Con Per PC | Max Con Per USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | U1 | 2020/01 | 1 | 1 |
| A | U2 | 2020/02 | 2 | 1 |
| A | U3 | 2020/03 | 3 | 1 |
| A | U4 | 2020/04 | 4 | 1 |
| B | U1 | 2020/01 | 1 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/02 | 2 | 2 |
| B | U2 | 2020/03 | 3 | 3 |

I need to create a "feature count" to check how many time "PC" found and "user" connected

**now for a machine learning algorithm what is the best way to do that? option 1 or option 2 or a combination**

- it's a classification problem.
- my target column is "is fraud" (Yes
  -1, No-0)